# is starttls.enabled = true is safe for mail sending from java code?

Tags: java, email, ssl, smtp

I'm sending emails from java code.My configuration is

```
 props.put("mail.smtp.starttls.enable", "true");
 props.put("mail.smtp.host", "****"); 
 props.put("mail.smtp.auth", "true");
 props.put("mail.smtp.port", "587");
```

On my [other question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18311294/is-starttlssmtp-the-same-with-smtp-over-ssl) [EJP](https://stackoverflow.com/users/207421/ejp) answered

> Any protocol that uses STARTTLS is in SSL mode after the STARTTLS
>   command is issued

But my debug output shows:DEBUG SMTP: trying to connect to host "****", port 587, isSSL false.

So my question sounds like

Is such configuration really safe and uses `SSL` as [EJP](https://stackoverflow.com/users/207421/ejp) said despite of isSSL=false on my debug output?

**UPDATE**

connecting code

```
 Transport transport = session.getTransport("smtp");
 transport.connect("host", 587,"username", "password");
```

when I wrote   `Transport transport = session.getTransport("smtps")` I got

```
javax.net.ssl.SSLException: Unrecognized SSL message, plaintext connection
```

Answer (score 2):

Set `mail.smtp.starttls.required=true`
This ensures TLS is used or connection won't happen
REF: https://javamail.java.net/nonav/docs/api/com/sun/mail/smtp/package-summary.html

Answer (score 1):

You should still use the 'smtp' transport as that is the protocol (smtps is not an known protocol). SSL is used for the connection. 
I myself have used 'javax.mail' in conjunction with Google. Google only allows SSL. So I can only answer yes; it works and it is safe. 
I should add that the property 'mail.smtp.starttls.enable' is a bit confusing. The startsll property refers to the command that is being issued but it should have been named: 'mail.smtp.secure.enable'.

Comment: Actually, there is another way to turn on SSL - `mail.smtp.ssl.enabled=true`. In that case output looks like isSSL=true, but our post server (MS Exchange 2007) doesn't support SSL but supports TLS. That's why I switched from SSL/465 to TLS/587, discovered that starttls produces isSSL=false and anwered this question